# MySQLi query about Is Empty Table Or Not?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to know is some table is empty or no, now I am realized this issue with this code:

```
// if table is empty it must return TRUE, if full FALSE

private function isEmpty($tableName)
{

    if ($result = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ?"))
    {

            $result->bind_param("s",$tableName);
            $result->execute();
            $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

            if (empty($row_cnt))
            {

                    return TRUE;

            }
            else
            {

                    return FALSE;

            }

    }

}
```

this code seems not a really perfect, I would like to know is there a better way to get the same results, but using predicat **SQL EXISTS** or something else? Thank you.

**updated:**
thanks for comments and answer, but anyway I dont have a clue how to do it, it's calls an error:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","database");

if ($result = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `talbe` LIMIT 1"))
{

    $row = $result->fetch_row();

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($row);
    echo "</pre>";

    $result->close();

}
$mysqli->close();
```

> [Sat Jun 09 11:25:34 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:
>   Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_row() in
>   F:\server\sites\home\test.loc\www\empty.php on line 9

**updated:**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","db");

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT 1"))
{

    if ($obj = $result->fetch_object())
    {

        echo "NOT EMPTY";

    }
    else
    {

        echo "empty";

    }


    $result->close();

}
$mysqli->close();
```

this is it.

Comment: I don't think you can easily prepare a table's name like that.

Comment: I still need a solution, I can't find a full example. This is seems so easy in mysql instead of mysqli.

Comment: Is there any danger at all that the table's name may be harmful? Does it come from the user?

Comment: nope, but who knows.. you know.. I solved. Wait for update.

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT(*)` is fine for determining if a table is empty, providing the table doesn't have huge number of rows.

Another alternative would be `SELECT (something) FROM ${table} LIMIT 1;` if that returns a result then the table isn't empty.

But are you sure it's possible to set table name via a parameter like that in mysqli?  I didn't think it was, need to check.

Comment: @Artefact2 err, `SELECT COUNT(*) LIMIT 1` will return the same as `SELECT COUNT(*)`, no? (ie I think LIMIT is applied after COUNT(*)).  Again, I need to check (it's been a long day!)

Comment: Ah yes, you're right, sorry about that. Well, just a plain "SELECT * LIMIT 1" should do the trick then.